# module npm file doesn't appear to me

Tags: javascript, npm, terminal

I am trying to follow with pluralsight tutorial and he wrote npm install on the terminal, then a file called npm module is installed on the folder he specified. when I try to install npm this appears to me in the terminal, and the directory which Im trying to install npm on it contains only one document called package-lock.json [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLwET.png)

Comment: and module npm file doesn't appear to me in the directory i specified

Comment: Did you install node.js? npm comes with node.js. You can download here https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Answer (score 0):

npm install uses the package.json to install the necessary packages

I can see when you ls, there's no package.json in the directory, just the package-lock which is created where ever you run npm install

Make sure you run the npm install from the same directory the package.json in contained in

Comment: please forget everything above and be with me.

Comment: the instructor went to https://github.com/pluralsight/web-dev-starter and copy the clone

Comment: then he went to the terminal and write git clone https://github.com/pluralsight/web-dev-starter.git

Comment: then he wrote in the terminal:

Comment: 1/ cd web-dev-starter

Comment: 2/ install npm ,

Comment: a folder called node_modules appears in web-dev-starter directory

Comment: this folder (node_module) is missing although I follow the exact steps with the instructor

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved, I think that I download the web-dev-starter folder twice by mistake.